# What's The Best(tm) way to install Emerald into Mint 12?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, repository

I understand that the Mint people seem to know what I want better than I do and all (kidding!) but I'd really like to get Emerald installed without resorting to compile from source.  So far I can't find a reliable place to point at to get it.

Comment: It's not about this question, but what "tm" means here ? Also have you tried `apt-get install emerald` yet

Comment: @warl0ck TM is a joke, it's meant to imply that there is one best way to do something.